# Nesting Find and sed command in if else

Tags: regex, bash, sed, find

I am using a find and sed command to replace characters in a file. see the code 1 below

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '/Subject/{:a;s/(Subject.*)Subject/\1SecondSubject/;tb;N;ba;:b}' {} +
```

Given that I have multiple files I need to replace. In a given situation, the Subject I am trying to replace is not available. 
Is there a way I can first check if the file contains the attribute 'Subject' if not I need to execute another command. i.e

Check if the file contains character 'Subject'

**If true then execute code1 above**

If there is no instance of Subject execute code 2 below

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec rename 's/.html$/.xml/' {} ;
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: use a `grep -r -l` instead of a find in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
find . -type f \( \
-exec grep -q "Subject" {} \; \
-exec sed -i '/Subject/{:a;s/(Subject.*)Subject/\1SecondSubject/;tb;N;ba;:b}' {} \; \
-o \
-exec rename 's/.html$/.xml/' {} \; \)
```

`-exec` takes the exit code of the command it executes, so `-exec grep -q "Subject" {} \;` will only be true if the grep is true. And since the short circuit `-o` (or) has a lower precedence than the implied `-a` (and) between the other operators it should conversely only get executed if the `grep` is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` in a process substitution like this:

```
while IFS= read -d'' -r file; do
    echo "processing $file ..."

    if grep -q "/Subject/" "$file"; then
       sed -i '{:a;s/(Subject.*)Subject/\1SecondSubject/;tb;N;ba;:b}' "$file"
    else if [[ $file == *.html ]]; then
       rename 's/.html$/.xml/' "$file"
    fi
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

Comment: Hi Anub.. I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks once again